# Install the same program twice with InstallShield?

Tags: installshield

Is there a `NoUninstall=Y` or similar option I can put into Setup.ini for a program?

I want to compare the behaviour of a patched and non-patched version of some software. To do that, I need 2 copies installed in different folders.

When I run setup.exe the second time, I am prompted to uninstall.

If I change `DoMaintenance=N` -> `DoMaintenance=Y`, I get the option to Modify, Repair, Uninstall.

I do not have access to the original InstallShield project files.

I'd like to avoid having to use Virtual PC.

Otherwise can I change the GUID of the first install within Windows/Regedit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure regarding changing GUIDs of installer in registry, but I guess it's possible, but the better will be change your setup. As I understood you have access to setup.ini, and perhaps you have access to msi? If so, you could change GUIDs of components, `PackageCode`, `UpgradeCode`, `ProductCode` and `ProductName` or `ProductVersion`.

P.S. For editing MSI you can use Orca, or more useful and also free InstEd.